# Need help in getting the count from table with clob column

Tags: sql, oracle

Table1 has 2 columns as follows

```
a with datatype Number
b with datatype clob
```

Data in Table1

```
a        |       b
100      | Rock+Y;Paper+No;Scissor+Yes;Dragon+Y;<br>
101      | Rock+N;Paper+No;Scissor+Yes;Dragon+N;<br>
102      | Rock+Y;Paper+Yes;Scissor+N;Dragon+Y;
```

In the first row of Table1, value of 'Rock' is Y , value of 'Paper' is No ,value of 'Scissor' is Yes and value of 'Dragon' is Y in column b.
I want to consider only Rock,Paper and Scissor with values Y,Yes and Yes respectively in column b for count. 
I want the count against column a based on column c's values.

Example:

For a=100,  Count only the attributes with values(Rock=Y, Paper=Yes,Scissor+Yes) 
i.e 2 as Rock's value is Y and Scissor's values is Yes.

Similarly,for a=101, count=1 because only Scissor has desired value i.e 'Yes' while Rock has 'N' and Paper has 'No'.

For a=102 , count=2 Rock and Paper has desired values i.e Y and Yes respectively.

How can I achieve this result?

Comment: I was about to write an answer to this, using `REGEXP_COUNT`, but then I read your explanation more carefully and I saw a discrepancy. You first say that for a=100 it should count only the "Y", not the "Yes" ones, then you counted 2 for a=101, which I can't justify, then you switch to counting 3 for a=102. I see no pattern here, or at least for now. Please try to express the exact criteria that needs to matched here - should the sing "Y" be counted, or it should count also "Yes" and if not always, specify these cases.

Comment: @mac07 - what query have tried writing for your problem. Maybe we can help you with fixing your query.

Comment: @g00dy For a=101 , it should count Rock if its value is Y, Paper if its value is Yes and Scissor if its values is Yes. Count will be 3 if Rock  is Y ,Paper is Yes and Scissor is Yes. Is it clear now?

Comment: @SudiptaMondal I was thinking of using Union but the table is huge and here I have shown only three attributes(Rock, Paper and Scissor) ( There are more than 15 attributes in my case).

Comment: @mac07 - what if "Scissors" = N (not to be confused with No), as it is the case with a=102? Is there any rule about the actual data - can it be either N, No, Y or Yes at any given time? Did you consider putting this data in a more structured format, like XML or JSON? If you can do it - I suggest you do, because it will make it simpler to analyse it later and deduct rules on it. Also, you didn't exactly specify a rule here, you've given an example. A rule will be valid for all values of column a. The case you provided will break on a=102, as I mentioned. Try to get the essence of it.

Answer (score 0):

If  you separate out the data into individual "attributes" then the answer can be done with simple SQL. SUBSTR function used here, but should also work with equivalent CLOB functions.

tab has sample data 
tab_attributes has the sample data separated out into attributes 
tab_nbr converts Y to 1 and N to  0 
final select just adds them up:

```
with tab as
(select 100 a, 'Rock+Y;Paper+No;Scissor+Yes;Dragon+Y;' b from dual union
select 101 a, 'Rock+N;Paper+No;Scissor+Yes;Dragon+N;' b from dual union
select 102 a, 'Rock+Y;Paper+Yes;Scissor+N;Dragon+Y;' b from dual 
)
, tab_attributes as
(
select a
, substr(b, instr(b, 'Rock+')+5,1) rock
, substr(b, instr(b, 'Paper+')+6,1) paper
, substr(b, instr(b, 'Scissor+')+8,1) scissor
from tab
)
, tab_nbr as
(select a
, case when rock = 'Y' then 1 when rock = 'N' then 0 else null end as rock 
, case when paper = 'Y' then 1 when paper = 'N' then 0 else null end as paper 
, case when scissor = 'Y' then 1 when scissor = 'N' then 0 else null end as scissor
from tab_attributes
)
select a, rock+paper+scissor cnt from tab_nbr
;
```